# Question about "safe websites"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the most appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask about safe websites? Currently, I am trying to find the best, most safe YouTube-to-MP3 converter, as *Ontiva* seems weird now (it was not weird until recently). I want to download a "sample" from a TV show scene, but all the sites for converting YouTube videos to MP3 format seem... suspicious.

Which platform on Stack Exchange should I use, if any?

Comment: Well, any site that deal with illegal stuff is most likely suspicious. I highly doubt you'll find any "safe" website that let you download YouTube videos, as it's not a legal action to begin with. [Good article explaining this](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/internet/is-it-legal-download-youtube-videos-3420353/).

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating   Actually, I am just making a song with this "sample" for fun. Nothing illegal, as it will never be publicly released. :)

Comment: Doesn't matter... once you convert the video to anything else you're essentially downloading it, and it doesn't matter why you do it. The action itself is illegal. One can steal apples from a shop to feed his starving kids; It's for noble cause, yet still illegal.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating No, this is different. It is the equivalent of me going to the library and getting a CD there, even though I did not pay for the CD (unless you get the overdue fee). What is the difference? These converter sites can be helpful, but they are generally abused.

Comment: The difference is that the owners of any CD you might get in library agreed for the library to give it, and the library likely paid for the right to do it (and if they didn't, this is most likely illegal as well). YouTube downloaders never get permission from YouTube or the content owners.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Hey, good point! I think the thing is for me is that I know of a teacher who downloaded a YouTube video via a converter site for their Zoom background... did they "steal" that? No, because YouTube to mp3/mp4 converters can be used for good. :)

Comment: Yes, the teacher "stole" it, aka got it in illegal way. Fair disclosure: I do it myself, sometimes, so can't judge! But this whole thing is around having "safe" websites for doing it, and alas... there can't be such, as the action itself isn't safe. That's my point, not trying to judge or make you not do it. :) (in my case, I download for personal use, to listen to songs via my phone.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I appreciate your friendly approach. I guess it depends on the definition of "steal" then. As per your article that you linked: "For personal use, no it is not illegal to download YouTube video. But it is immoral." However, my use of this is not immoral, as I am not trying to avoid ads or streaming-quality issues. The article even suggests that "at the end of the day, it's really up to you to decide whether or not downloading video from YouTube for personal use is something you should be doing." :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question is effectively asking for recommendations, I'm not sure how much mileage you'll get on any SE site. *Maybe* [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), possibly [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)? Alas, I'm unfamiliar with both, so check their rules.

<del>Also, you should bear in mind that since downloading YouTube videos is... legally ambiguous, at the very least, it may not fly anywhere on SE, and might be disallowed on either of those sites for this reason alone; check their respective rules for specifics.</del>
*See links below, I found questions on both sites asking about this very topic, see if those answer your question outright before asking another on those sites.

If SE won't allow it, it's possible that Reddit might be a good alternative, I'm sure there are some relevant subreddits that could be helpful to you.

---

Links of interest:

- Software Recommendations:

  - Help Center - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - Meta - [Shall this site support questions on youtube downloaders?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/805/shall-this-site-support-questions-on-youtube-downloaders)
  - Main - [Software to download YouTube videos to hard drive](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/817/software-to-download-youtube-videos-to-hard-drive)
- Web Applications:

  - Help Center - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - Main - [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)